# Connect to oracle database with C++

Tags: c++, oracle, connection

I am looking for a way to connect to an remote oracle database and read some data from  table within a c++ console application.
Can some one give me some hints.
Thnx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

soci, http://soci.sourceforge.net, is a reasonably modern C++ interface that uses the Oracle call interface. And can also connect to other databases ...

Comment: Will it work for remote Oracle database ?? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @W.Jack It uses the Oracle Call Interface from the Oracle client underneath, so yes, I expect it would work for remote Oracle databases.

Answer (score 5):

The official Oracle website proposes several resources. Amongst others:

- [Oracle C++ Call Interface](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090820.html)
- [Develop C and C++ Applications with Oracle Database 11g Using OCI](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/oci/oci.htm)

Just google, there are really plenty of tutorials around.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the [Oracle C++ Call Interface (native API)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090820.html) or the [Open DataBase Connectivity API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714562%28VS.85%29.aspx).  If you want a more high-level wrapper, there are some more convenient interfaces in libraries such as [Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/database.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use OCCI: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090820.html

or OCI: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html

or one of many other APIs available.. It really depends on the type of thing you're going to use it for.. You should find a lot of information about the pros/cons of the various APIs through google..

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's study purpose or strict requirement with ORACLE DB, I'd suggest you to work with generic classes/services provided with various Microsoft Framework.

- [Data Access Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd4ck1tt%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- [MFC Database classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h81kkytb%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- [ATL Database classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8k76sd16%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- Of course [ORCACLE C++ IF is also available.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090820.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try: [`CODBC`](http://www.codbc.com). It is an API for `Pro*C`. `Pro*C` is a very decent way to connect Oracle and C++.

Answer (score -1):

Currently (2021) actively developed is also [OCILIB](http://vrogier.github.io/ocilib/), I was able to setup the test example in short time.